# how to keybind shortcuts with vim autocmd FileType?

Tags: vim

I have these lines in my vimrc file:

```
autocmd FileType js nnoremap <F5> :! node % <CR>
autocmd FileType cpp nnoremap <F5> :! g++ % -o %.out && ./%.out <CR>
autocmd FileType py nnoremap <F5> :! python % <CR>
```

Problem: compiling and running cpp files with <kbd>F5</kbd> works normally, but js and py files can't run, I think the shortcut is not being executed at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of vim's filetype for python is "python", not "py". See also [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/24899/4866). Similarily, it's "javascript", not "js". However, "cpp" is fine.

So the first and third lines should be:

```
autocmd FileType javascript nnoremap :! node %
autocmd FileType python nnoremap :! python %
```